# Can not clone row, template variable not found or variable contains markup

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

I'm using phpword and laravel 10. I want to display the peserta_kegiatan (activity participant) data on a table in MS Word. I tried this way, but the error appears: "Can not clone row, template variable not found or variable contains markup". What's wrong?
This is the code I have tried:

```
public function pesertaKegiatans()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PesertaKegiatan::class, 'proposal_pkm_id');
}

$pesertaKegiatans = $proposal->pesertaKegiatans;
$pesertas = [];
foreach ($pesertaKegiatans as $peserta) {
        $pesertas[] = [
            "nama_mahasiswa" => $peserta->nama_peserta,
            "nim_mahasiswa" => $peserta->nim,
            "prodi_mahasiswa" => $peserta->program_studi,
            "peminatan_mahasiswa" => $peserta->peminatan
        ];
    }
$template->cloneRowAndSetValues('nama_mahasiswa', $pesertas);
```

This is my MS Word template:
[image]

Comment: just modify the line $pesertaKegiatans = $proposal->pesertaKegiatans; with $pesertaKegiatans = $proposal->pesertaKegiatans()->get(); try also to chain ->toArray() at the end and see if you can skip the foreach loop and use directly $template->cloneRowAndSetValues('nama_mahasiswa', $pesertaKegiatans);